# Microsoft Graph: is there a way to un-cancel a recurrence in a recurring event?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

A bit of context: we have a system which stores recurring events in the RRULE format and we have the EXDATE part which stores exceptions. Obviously we can add and remove exceptions for the whole serie by just adding/removing entries in the EXDATE section of it.

We wanna basically sync our system with an outlook calendar, but apparently in MS Graph there is no concept of an event with exceptions, or at least I could find anything similar. All I could do is to remove an occurrence from series, which is fine.

But the restoring doesn's seem to be supported at all. I am wondering if there is a way of restoring a deleted event? Or rather is there any better way than removing the whole serie and start over again?

Comment: Same problem here, but no solution :(